# Rewriting and saving HTML code by JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a problem, and do not know how I can solve it.

I have a little site, on shared folder, wich may be used only inside it, so I can not use backend at this site. Only, JS, only HTML, only hardcore!!! and I need to change HTML and permanently save it. For eg.:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(id){
    var tbody = document.getElementById('sem')
    var row = document.createElement("TR")
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
    td1.innerHTML = "<b>I'm HERE!!!</b>"
    row.appendChild(td1);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
</script>
<a href="javascript://" onclick="addRow();return false;">Place it!</a>
<table>
    <tbody id="sem">
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nothing</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

it changes my code well, but as it expected, after reload all changes disappear. I need smth like `.write()` function, to make my changes permanent. I know nothing about JS working with files. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Filesystem access is forbidden to javascript. you need to store the data on server/ database and retrieve it through javascript queries and re-create the page

Comment: You won't be able to overwrite the files with JS. I think the best you  could do is use local client storage, but those changes will only persist for that particular client machine / browser. Other users will not be able to see them. (this is all assuming no backend technology, otherwise a database would be the best solution)

Comment: I can not use any DB or server. It is a very-very little project for stuff, wich should not be used in outer from local folder. I want to mare it editable by others, so that project will not depends only on myself.

Comment: @Pruntoff: you can't do this via JavaScript.

Comment: Ok. I see. Will close that question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way to do it. Filesystem access is forbidden to javascript.
Thanks for @Akshay Khandelwal, @musefan, @Paul D. Waite